# Filezilla lets to duplicate files with utf8 filenames in same folder

Tags: filezilla

When I'm uploading all folder tree with all files, filezilla corrupts files with utf8 filenames. It writes them there, the files are OK, but they isn't served by nginx.

When I open some folder and select files from my computer same folder, draging them by hand, they duplicates, but these new files, are shown by nginx!

So if I originally uploaded 6 files to current folder when uploading all folders tree, then opening just this one current folder Filezilla lets me again to upload same 6 files, but it becomes as 12 files. When I select to drag files again, it won't become 18, Filezilla overwriting these 6 which I had draged by hand, leaves another 6 untouched.

I have about 2000 different folders in my folders tree, with files inside. When I upload all folder tree, no files which has utf8 in filename are shown by nginx. When I open every dir and redrag files by hand, they start work on nginx, also they are draged as new ones in that folder as I said before.

Resume: 
Filezilla uploading files somehow wrong when uploading all folder tree... But Correctly when dragging only files.

Comment: Not a programming question. Off-topic. Please move it to [su]. And you haven't even told us, what protocol (FTP or SFTP) are you using. Or what encoding does the server use natively.

Answer (score 1):

I googled for you, and found this advice:

> I am not sure if it solves your problem, but try under "File
>   server manager" "character set" and there force UTF-8.

Comment: I put that checkbox also, but it didn't solved the problem. It is still writing files somehow wrong when uploading all folder tree... And Corectly when dragging only files.